# Issues with Asp.net Gridview Paging

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have used the Gridview_PageIndexChanging event in asp.net.i have used the code like this:

```
gridFileDetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
```

During the run time when i clicked the next page,it generates an error:

> An exception of type
>   'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in FFK.DLL but was not handled in user
>   code
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast
>   object of type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder'
>   to type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'.

in the RowCommand event,

I have used the following RowCommand event:

```
Protected Sub gridFileDetails_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gridFileDetails.RowCommand

    Dim row As GridViewRow = CType(CType(e.CommandSource, Control).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
    Dim rowkey As DataKey = Me.gridFileDetails.DataKeys(row.DataItemIndex)
    Dim key As String = rowkey(0).ToString()
    If e.CommandName = "FileStatus" And e.CommandArgument <= 0 Then
        Response.Redirect("FFKFile.aspx?FileId=" + key)
    ElseIf e.CommandName = "TradexStatus" And e.CommandArgument <= 0 Then
        Response.Redirect("TradeX.aspx?FileId=" + key)
    ElseIf e.CommandName = "BondStatus" And e.CommandArgument <= 0 Then
        Response.Redirect("BondMaster.aspx?FileId=" + key)
    ElseIf e.CommandName = "FDStatus" And e.CommandArgument <= 0 Then
        Response.Redirect("FrmFileDocument.aspx?FileId=" + key)
    ElseIf e.CommandName = "InvoiceStatus" And e.CommandArgument <= 0 Then
        Response.Redirect("InvoiceMaster.aspx?FileId=" + key)
    ElseIf e.CommandName = "PDStatus" And e.CommandArgument <= 0 Then
        Response.Redirect("PackagingDetails.aspx?FileId=" + key)
    End If
End Sub
```

can you resolve this problem?
i am getting the error in the first line in RowCommand event ,ie.,

```
Dim row As GridViewRow = CType(CType(e.CommandSource, Control).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
```

In the PageIndexChanging event i have written as follows:

Protected Sub gridFileDetails_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles gridFileDetails.PageIndexChanging
        gridFileDetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    End Sub

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you posted your ASPX code.

Comment: Protected Sub gridFileDetails_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles gridFileDetails.PageIndexChanging
        gridFileDetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
Dim row As GridViewRow = CType(CType(e.CommandSource, Control).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
```

Use the index from the `EventArgs` to grab the row programmatically like this:

```
Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
Dim row As GridViewRow = gridFileDetails.Rows(index)
```

Comment: when i tried ur code,i got the following error:

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: This means your grid has no data - check to make sure that the gridview has been databound.  Perhaps you are not loading the data on postback and your gridview has viewstate disabled?

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the exception you are seeing.

Comment: i am getting this error:

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: That is the exception message, I would like to see the stack trace which is the block of text after the message which shows which methods were called prior to the error.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing the MSDN for the [System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewcommandeventargs.aspx) class, the example there for extracting the gridviewrow is this:

```
  ' Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
  ' property to an Integer.
  Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)

  ' Retrieve the row that contains the button clicked 
  ' by the user from the Rows collection.
  Dim row As GridViewRow = ContactsGridView.Rows(index)
```

See if that helps you get your row without the cast error.

Comment: when i tried ur code,i got the following error: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: Have you tried the debugger to see what your objects are instantiated with when this method is run?  For example, what is the index that is passed in the e.CommandArgument, and what is the current value of gridFileDetails.Rows?

Comment: gridFileDetails.Rows.Count returns the value '10'

Comment: And what is the value of e.CommandArgument?  If it is greater than 10, or less than 0, then that would cause the out of range value.

Comment: Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)

index returns the value '2'

Comment: So is the out of range exception happening on the MSDN example code? Or is it occurring on another line from your code?  The stacktrace of the exception should trace it back to the offending index.  The rowKey(0), for example, would fail if rowKey is null or has a length of 0.

Answer (score 1):

This might help :

```
Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
Dim row As GridViewRow = gridFileDetails.Rows(index)
```